# numpy: determine the corresponding float datatype from a complex datatype

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-dtype

I'm using two numpy arrays of floating point numbers

```
Rs = np.linspace(*realBounds, realResolution, dtype=fdtype)
Is = np.linspace(*imagBounds, imagResolution, dtype=fdtype)
```

to make a grid `Zs` of complex numbers with shape `(realResolution, imagResolution)`. I'd like to only specify the datatype of `Zs` and use this to determine the float datatype `fdtype`.

As I understand it from [this page](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html), complex datatypes are always represented as two floats with the same datatype, hence why `Rs` and `Is` both have `dtype=fdtype`. If the datatype of `Zs` is specified as `np.csingle` then I'd like `fdtype` to be `np.single`, if it's specified as `np.dtype("complex128")` then I'd like `fdtype` to be `np.dtype("float64")`, and so on. Is there a nice way to do this?

**Edit**: I'm equally interested in the inverse function which sends, for example, `np.single` to `np.csingle`.

Comment: Do you mean? `Is = np.linspace(*imagBounds, imagResolution, dtype=Rs.dtype)`

Comment: @hpaulj I don't think I see how this will change things. How is this better than using `fdtype` for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is such a function in numpy but you can easily roll your own using [`num`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.num.html), which uniquely identifies each of the built-in types:

```
def get_corresonding_dtype(dt):
    return {11: np.csingle,
            12: np.cdouble,
            13: np.clongdouble,
            14: np.single,
            15: np.double,
            16: np.longdouble}[np.dtype(dt).num]
```

The dict was obtained from `{np.dtype(dt).num: dt for dt in (np.single, np.double, np.longdouble, np.csingle, np.cdouble, np.clongdouble)}` which returns

```
{11: numpy.float32,
 12: numpy.float64,
 13: numpy.longdouble,
 14: numpy.complex64,
 15: numpy.complex128,
 16: numpy.clongdouble}
```

on `win-amd64` (`sysconfig.get_platform()`). The names may vary, e.g. on `linux-x86_64` it shows `numpy.complex256` instead of `numpy.clongdouble`, but thanks to `num` you don't need to pay attention to it.

So for instance for all of `np.double`, `np.float_`, `np.float64`, `float`, `'float64'` etc., `get_corresonding_dtype` will return `numpy.complex128`.

If you like you can also add `np.half` as `23: np.csingle` to the dict, as there's no complex half/float16 type in numpy.